# Logic issue in code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code, where I am trying to shift p position by value 1 and in cyclic order, for example `p[1]=p[0], p[2]=p[1].... till p[4]=p[0]`
I applied the following logic, but all I am getting is only p[0] all the time, can anyone please suggest something..

```
p=[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]


def move(p, U):
    q=[]
    for i in range(len(p)):
        print p[i]
        m=(U+i)%(len(p))
        p[m]=p[i]

    q=p
    return q
print move(p, 1)
```

Comment: Try printing `p` at every step of your loop to see what's going wrong

Comment: you are rewriting ``p[m]`` without saving its old value to reuse it in the next iteration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    m=(U+i)%(len(p))
    p[m]=p[i]
```

Right here you're modifying your list as you're iterating through it. That's a no-no. Try making a new list first and modifying that.

```
q = [None for _ in range(len(p))]  # q has length == len(p), filled with None
for i, value in enumerate(p):
    print value
    m = (U+i) % len(p)
    q[m] = value
```

I also use `enumerate` here which is more idiomatic when you need both the index and the value of an iterable.

---

Note that if you're trying for efficiency here instead of algorithm practice, [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=deque#deque-objects) is your friend. A deque is a double-ended queue, so it supports efficient pops and inserts from the start and the end. It also has a `rotate` function that does exactly this.

```
from collections import deque

d = deque(p)
# d = deque([1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
d.rotate(-1)  # rotate left by an index
# d = deque([1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
d.rotate(1)  # rotate right by an index
# d = deque([1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
d.rotate(1)  # rotate right by an index
# d = deque([0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way to do this:

```
p.insert(0, p.pop())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with slicing the list.

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

```
def move(my_list=None, step=None):
    return my_list[step:] + my_list[:step]
print move(my_list=l, step=1)
print move(my_list=l, step=2)
print move(my_list=l, step=-1)
```

Output

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```